# Why can't unix find enumerate everything beneath /sys?

Tags: linux, find

I'd like to be locate every device that has a rescan option/file beneath /sys/devices (so that I can resize disks on the fly), but UNIX find doesn't seem to find them.  For example:

```
# file /sys/class/block/sda/device/rescan
/sys/class/block/sda/device/rescan: writable, regular file, no read permission
```

But:

```
# find /sys/class/block -name 'rescan'
```

Comes back empty.

Further, find is only finding the parent device, i.e.

```
# find /sys/class/block 
/sys/class/block
/sys/class/block/fd0
/sys/class/block/sda
/sys/class/block/sr0
/sys/class/block/dm-0
/sys/class/block/dm-1
/sys/class/block/dm-2
/sys/class/block/sda1
/sys/class/block/sda2
/sys/class/block/sda3
```

When there are actually lots of options/files located under these devices (if you know where to look), for example:

```
# ls -1 /sys/class/block/sda/device/
block
bsg
delete
device_blocked
device_busy
dh_state
driver
eh_timeout
evt_capacity_change_reported
evt_inquiry_change_reported
evt_lun_change_reported
evt_media_change
evt_mode_parameter_change_reported
evt_soft_threshold_reached
generic
inquiry
iocounterbits
iodone_cnt
ioerr_cnt
iorequest_cnt
modalias
model
power
queue_depth
queue_ramp_up_period
queue_type
rescan
rev
scsi_device
scsi_disk
scsi_generic
scsi_level
state
subsystem
timeout
type
uevent
unpriv_sgio
vendor
vpd_pg80
vpd_pg83
wwid
```

Thanks in Advance,

Patrick

Comment: Run `ls -l /sys/class/block` and inspect the results.

Answer (score 0):

The contents beneath */sys* contain many symbolic links, like the *parent devices* you want to search in */sys/class/block*.
`find` does not follow symbolic links by default, meaning `find` will not search in directories which are symbolic links.

One can change this behavior with the `-L` switch of `find` to make it follow symbolic links.
Due to the nature of */sys* and the many symbolic links in this directory structure, `find` will detect *file system loops* and report that on the command line on `stderr`. To filter out these messages you could run your `find` command as follows.

```
find -L /sys/class/block -name 'rescan' 2> /dev/null
```